# Unable to delete Amazon RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am unable to delete a RDS instance in my account.

The error message shows:

> IAM Database Authentication is enabled in the DB Instance but it is not supported for the new configuration from the request. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 332fe09b-d6a0-47c8-84bc-d1f6881f34d2)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [disabling IAM Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Enabling.html) before deleting the instance?

Comment: I do not even get the option of  IAM DB authentication  in "Database options" , when modifying this instance